# lightroom style "image stacking" with actual files and folders on HDD?

Tags: lightroom, image-stacking, automation

Lightroom classic has [photo stacking feature](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/grouping-photos-stacks.html#automatically_stack_photos_by_capture_time) that can divide loaded images in stacks (folders) based on difference between capture time (timestamp).

Need same functionality outside lightroom in windows explorer with actual image files and folders on my hard drive.
Want to open folder in windows explorer and have images stacked into sub-folders based on capture time in same manner lightroom does it.

Any software can do it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a digital asset management question... not sure it really belongs here.

Windows *[file explorer](https://xmlandmore.blogspot.com/2021/06/windowswant-to-sort-files-by-type-and.html)* allows you to organize files by time/date/etc, but it does have limited functionality.

Otherwise you can use something like [PhotoMove](https://www.mjbpix.com/) to automatically sort images into separate groupings (folders).